# C# Automapper Ignore property when different type

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping where the source and destination property share a name, but have different types.

I am trying to completely ignore the property, but I keep getting an exception:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(x => x.MemberToIgnore, y => y.Ignore());
```

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.

Comment: That question doesn't have an accepted answer, and none of the answers actually work.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.